# Amazon Aurora CREATE_TIME in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES is NULL

Tags: amazon-rds, information-schema

We are running an Amazon Aurora database that emulates MySQL 5.6.10. The CREATE_TIME in SHOW TABLE STATUS *and* INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES is consistently NULL for all our tables.

Is this a bug, a limitation of Aurora's architecture, or am I doing something wrong? Is this information available anyplace else?

```
db2 information_schema> SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA 
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE CREATE_TIME IS NOT NULL;
+--------------------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA       |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (9.00 sec)
```

Additional notes: We have several thousand tables across several hundred databases, on several different hosts; many of the tables were created with files-per-table on, and some with it off. We do not have access to the .frm files, and they may or may not exist in Aurora. This has always worked for us in MySQL.

Update: Amazon support told us, vaguely, this is a bug and "it will be corrected in a later release." Still interested in knowing if this is going to be retroactively available, or if there is another place to get this 'cause Amazon is not elaborating.

Comment: We've also just hit this issue. I've raised a ticket with AWS. We're looking at using the `TABLE_COMMENT` column and writing our own date time stamp as we only need this for a brand new feature that is not yet live.

Comment: This is still an issue for 5.7.12 as of August 2019.

Comment: Still issue as of February 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the response from AWS - they agree using the TABLE_COMMENT column is the way forward. I can also confirm we have successfully implemented this solution.

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting AWS premium support. My name is Vidyadhar and
>   I am glad to assist you on this case.
>
> From the case description, I understand that you noticed only null
>   values in create_time column in information_schema.tables. You were
>   removing old tables based on the values inside this column in MySQL.
>   Now, you would like to know reason for not showing up creation time in
>   Aurora and alternatives to achieve your requirement.
>
> Just to let you know, there is a known bug in MySQL related to the
>   same where create_time will be null for partitioned columns. This has
>   been fixed in MySQL 5.6.25 version. Please look into below link for
>   reference.
>
> https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69990
>
> In aurora this column will be NULL for all tables including
>   partitioned tables. This has been already notified to the service
>   team. Also, there is no workaround to this available in Aurora for
>   now.
>
> It is best option to utilize the table comment session as a work
>   around to note the time of table creation and proceed accordingly with
>   table deletion. You can look into TABLE_COMMENT column in
>   information_schema.tables. Please refer to below example which might
>   be helpful.
>
> ```
> MySQL [test]> create table S1(id int) comment='2017-09-21 15:53:51';
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
>
> MySQL [test]>  show create table S1\G
> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>        Table: S1 Create Table: CREATE TABLE `S1` (   `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
> COMMENT='2017-09-21 15:53:51' 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
>
> MySQL [test]> select TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,TABLE_COMMENT from
> information_schema.tables where table_schema='test' and
> table_name='S1';
> +--------------+------------+---------------------+ 
> | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | TABLE_COMMENT       |
> +--------------+------------+---------------------+ 
> | test         | S1         | 2017-09-21 15:53:51 |
> +--------------+------------+---------------------+ 
> 1 row in set (0.01 sec)
> ```
>
> I truly apologize for the inconvenience caused. Aurora service team is
>   working hard to add features and fixing bugs. As of now, I am unable
>   to provide any ETA but definitely this will be fixed in future
>   versions.
>
> I hope this information is helpful. Please feel free to reach me if
>   you have any further questions or concerns.
>
> Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Even it isn't exactly the CREATE_TIME, I think it could be usefull to put here that you can find some equivalents to the UPDATE_TIME, and that the file .frm exist but are not visible.

You can actually found what seems to be the latest time of an alteration with this query:

```
SELECT filename, FROM_UNIXTIME(last_update) FROM mysql.metadata_md_table
WHERE filename LIKE "./YOUR_SCHEMA/YOUR_TABLE%";
```

Replacing YOUR_SCHEMA and YOUR_TABLE by your expected value, you will see that .frm files exist with Aurora (but you can't access them as you don't have access to the filesystem...), but in this table, they are associate to a last_update timestamp.

I don't find any specific information about this table, but with my own test, it seems that this date is set at creation of the table, then at each ALTER TABLE perform on this same table...

The comment at the creation with the creation_date information is probably the best solution for a creation_date, but maybe this answer can be useful in this context of Aurora limitations.